Prevent faceting to update one data stream within a SAQL Query
The current query includes 2 data streams.
The first calculates the numerator, the second calculates the denominator.
If you select one of the two stacked values, it then facets to other widgets with the same query with the exception of the dimension which is being projected.
In this cases, Geo and then Market.
The issue with the query is that any facet selection filters both the numerator with the same values and renders the results as 100% for other query widgets.
The requirement is to facet the numerator only and the denominator should reflect the "total" values for the specified dimension.
Example:
numerator part 1 = 20 and numerator part 2 = 10.  The numerator total is 30.
denominator = 100 total
30/100 = 30%
If the user selects the numerator part 1 = 20, then the results should be 20/100 or 20%.   This would require the denominator to remain unfaceted.
Any suggestions?  I thought about creating a base query which would exclude faceting, and then pass the unfaceted denominator values to the other query.   Have no idea how this would be possible via a Binding, if at all.
Thank you in advance for your ideas and responses.


